# MySQL UPDATE doesn't work with PHP if

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a value from my SQL database. But something doesn't work, but I don't know why. This is the insert.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$id = $_GET["id"];
$rating = $_GET["rating"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db('...',$con);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
echo mysql_error();

if($rating=='likes' || $rating=='dislikes'){
if($rating=='likes'){
    $sql1 = "UPDATE artikel SET likes='likes+1' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    echo "Danke für deine Bewertung!";
} else {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE artikel SET dislikes='dislikes+1' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    echo "Danke für deine Bewertung! Nutze doch auch die Kommentarfunktion, um uns zu sagen was dir nicht gefallen hat.";
}} else {
    echo "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Probiere es bitte noch einmal.";
}


?>
```

Comment: first of all please use mysqli_* because mysql_* is deprecated. dont mix them

Comment: You can't mix mysql_connect with mysqli_query

Comment: This condition is obsolete `if($rating=='likes' || $rating=='dislikes'){`

Comment: you only mysql or mysqli don't marge up it in one.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you are mixing mysqli and mysql (only use mysqli or PDO) as mentioned in the comments, you have a logic error in your sql:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE artikel SET likes='likes+1' WHERE id='$id'";
```

This will try to set the value of the `likes` field to the string `"likes+1"`. If you want to update your `likes` value, you need to remove the quotes:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE artikel SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$id'";
```

The same applies to your other sql statement.

Apart from that you also have an **sql injection problem**. You should only use PDO or mysqli and use a prepared statement. Your statement would then look something like:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE artikel SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=?";
```

Then you prepare this statement, bind the variable to the placeholder (the question mark) and you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quotation from likes or dislikes:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE artikel SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$id'";
$sql2 = "UPDATE artikel SET dislikes=dislikes+1 WHERE id='$id'";
```